# Is there a down side to returning an IEnumerable<T> via an infinite loop yielding elements?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, infinite-loop

Is the infinite loop here causing any negative impact?  Resharper warns me that the..

> Function never returns

..but I can't see any downside here.

```
public static class RandomEntityFactory
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>() where T : class
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return Get<T>();
        }
    }

    public static T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Client)) return CreateRandomClient() as T;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Font)) return CreateRandomFont() as T;

        throw new Exception("unknown type: " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: To me this seems to be the kind of code that looks clever when you come up with it, but blows up a couple months from now during a bugfix session. Most code is probably written with the expectation that an `IEnumerable` holds a finite number of items (a `foreach` without `break`, `.ToArray()`, and so on), and even when this method would make it obvious that it returns an infinite sequence (by naming it `GetInfiniteEntities`) the result could easily 'leak' into other methods, where the origin of that sequence is not obvious anymore.

Comment: Very interesting. Got my gears turning. (hi Aaron!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a downside?

It depends on the intended usage. As written, some Linq functions - primarily `All` and `Count` - will never complete. Linq queries that use deferred execution would be fine so long as the consumer has a way to break the loop at some point.  Clients will have to be sure to use deterministic functions such as `Take` or `First` (assuming at some point a return value will meet the condition).

If the intended usage is to let clients enumerate with a `foreach`, breaking the loop at their discretion, then it's reasonable to return items indefinitely.

Comment: I don't think `Where` belongs in that list.  `Enuemrate<Client>().Where(c=>c.SomeBooleanProperty).Take(10);`

Comment: If you remove the `Take` it will still return immediately, it just won't stop when you iterate it.  Where as `All` and `Count` will hang.

Comment: It's worse than just that.  Even operations such as `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` iterate the entire source sequence in order to compute even a single value, so the second you use either of those on an infinite sequence you create a sequence that you can never get even a single item out of.

Answer (score 2):

Having an "infinite" enumerable does not cause any problems by itself. The particular code you have written looks very odd though. I would do it this way instead:

```
static IEnumerable<long> Iota()
{
    long i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return i;
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is the general-purpose sequence 0, 1, 2, ...

If you want to make an endless sequence of random fonts, you can do this:

```
Iota().Select(_ => CreateRandomFont())
```

This avoids writing your `Get` method, which looks bad to me.